# Install4j JRE bundling process breaks the SHA hash of lib jars?

Tags: install4j

I am using Install4j 5.1.11 to create a Windows installer for my application. I need to embed JRE version 1.7.0_72 with it. This particular version of JRE is not available in the Install4j JRE download list. So I create a bundle manually by pointing Install4j to `C\Program Files\Java\jdk_1.7.0_72\jre`. Install4j creates a bundle `C:\Program Files (x86)\install4j5\jres\windows-amd64-1.7.0_72.tar.gz`. Cool. Now in the media file wizard, I select this JRE bundle to embed and build my installer.

Then I run the built installer and install my application. I can see that the `jre` is unpacked under the installation home directory and has the same version `1.7.0_72`. Cool. So now I launch the application using the exe launcher which starts up Tomcat and loads applications etc and uses the embedded jre for the same. For one of the web application (called Fieldbook) while Tomcat is loading the context, I get the error shown below:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Fieldbook]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1120)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1678)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for javax/crypto/CipherSpi.class
 at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(ManifestEntryVerifier.java:220)
 at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:241)
 at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
 at java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(JarVerifier.java:483)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:237)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:114)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2293)
```

What is going on? Why and how did the SHA hash of the CipherSpi.class became different from what is in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of the `jce.jar` which is usually part of the `jre/lib`s?

Comment: This is probably related to pack200. In the JRE bundle wizard, please deselect the "Pack JAR files" check box on the "Select JRE" step and create a new bundle. Does the problem then go away?

Comment: I'm sorry, that feature only exists since 6.0. You can use 6.0 to create a bundle that will also work with 5.1.15

Comment: Thanks Ingo Kegel. In the Install4j 5.1.11 version I am using, there is no "Pack Jar files" checkbox on the "Select JRE" step of the wizard. I do however have "Use Pack200 Jar Compression (Only with Java >=1.5)" option under General Settings -> Media File Options -> Compression section, and is **not** ticked. I do have "Use LZMA Compression" option ticked under the same settings though, can that be the cause too?

Comment: No, only pack200 could cause such a problem. The JRE bundles are packed regardless of the settings in the media file section. In version 6.0 the JRE bundle creation wizard has an option to disable pack200.

Comment: @IngoKegel I downloaded Install4j 6.0.1 (for Windows 64-bit) and installed with the 90 day evaluation license. Unfortunately the custom JRE bundle creation wizard screen (the screen that is loaded by "I cannot find a suitable JRE bundle" link) is not loading at all ! There is no message either. Nothing happens on clicking this link. Another bug?

Comment: Project->Create a JRE bundle from the main menu?

Comment: Oh cool. That loads the wizard fine. Thanks! I created a bundle via Install4j 6 and used in in my Install4j 5 project which works fine. Thanks for all your help @IngoKegel.

Comment: @IngoKegel I have summarised the discussion above and posted an answer. Please review. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install4j 5.x versions apply Pack 200 compression when creating JRE bundles. This compression option is not configurable. Compression ends up modifying the contents of the JRE package which breaks signed and digest marked jar files such as `jce.jar` which is part of JRE lib.

Workaround is to use Install4j v6.x to create JRE bundle with the new "Pack Jar files" option unchecked which allows compression to be disabled. These bundles can then be used in Install4j 5.x projects (by putting them under Install4j installation's **jres** folder) to embed in media files.